# Tell Vue to look at all the pictures in a folder without changing the names of the images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I made a way to tell Vue to look in a file and assign images to the corresponding amount of cards. It's working fine.

But I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. The reason why I am asking is that currently, you need to rename your images in numerical order (Eg. 1.png,2.png,3.png etc) and as you know it's very bad for SEO to not name your Image files properly and its a tad bit annoying if you want to add more images or remove any

This is not a complete deal breaker but I would like it if I do not lose on my SEO ranking capabilities.

Here is the code

```
<v-container fluid>
            <v-row>
              <v-col
                v-for="n in 38"
                :key="n"
                class="d-flex child-flex"
                cols="4"
              >
                <v-lazy
                  :options="{
                    threshold: 0.5,
                  }"
                  transition="fade-transition"
                >
                  <v-card elevation="8" shaped draggable="false" class="d-flex">
                    <v-img
                      :src="require('@/assets/skillsLogo/' + n + '.png')"
                      :lazy-src="require('@/assets/skillsLogo/' + n + '.png')"
                      class="grey lighten-4"
                      aspect-ratio="3"
                    >
                      <template v-slot:placeholder>
                        <v-row
                          class="fill-height ma-0"
                          align="center"
                          justify="center"
                        >
                          <v-progress-circular
                            indeterminate
                            color="grey lighten-5"
                          ></v-progress-circular>
                        </v-row>
                      </template>
                    </v-img>
                  </v-card>
                </v-lazy>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `require.context('@/assets/skillsLogo', false, /\.png$/)` to get an Object with all files in the given folder - then you can enumerate it.

Comment: Thanks @IVOGELOV for the swift reply. Its giving me an error in console if I use that.
 `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "src". Expected String, Object, got Function`

Comment: `require.context()` is not a direct replacement for `require()` - you should create a computed property in your component and call it inside, then prepare an array and return it as a result for the computed property. Then use this computed property as a source in `v-for`

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks man, I understand now. thanks for the awesome help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`images.js`

```js
const context = require.context("@/assets/skillsLogo/", false, /\.png$/);
const images = context.keys().map(context);

export default images;
```

[Docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext)

Component:

```js
<script>
import images from "./images.js";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      images: images,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Iterate over `images` array in your template...